# Selecting Subcollections in Union-Query

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to select objects from the database with Entity Framework into an anonymous type. When using Union and Selecting a Subcollection, I get an exception:

> System.ArgumentException: The 'Distinct' operation cannot be applied to the collection ResultType of the specified argument.

My model contains several types derived from `BaseType`. This base type has a reference to `RefType` which contains a collection of `ItemType`. The types derived from `BaseType` are stored in separate tables, thus the Union.

The query looks like this:

```
var q1 = ctx.Set<Type1>().Select(x => new { x.Id, x.Ref.Items });
var q2 = ctx.Set<Type2>().Select(x => new { x.Id, x.Ref.Items });
q1.Union(q2).ToList();
```

But to reproduce the error, you can even union queries of the same type, as long as you select a collection.

I would do the select after the union, but to union `Type1`, `Type2`, etc. I must cast them to `BaseType`, which is not allowed in LINQ-to-SQL.

Any way to do this in the same query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exception emerges from Entity Framework's query generation pipeline when the `ExpressionConverter` tries to translate the expression `q1.Union(q2)` into SQL.

In a valid query you'll see that EF adds a `DISTINCT` clause to the SQL query. A type with collection properties (`x.Ref.Items`) doesn't pass as a valid argument for a `Distinct` operation and EF throws the exception you see.

Unfortunately, using `Concat` instead of `Union` is not a valid work-around. EF will also throw an exception:

> The nested query is not supported. Operation1='UnionAll' Operation2='MultiStreamNest'

Which means that it's simply not supported to concat nested queries containing types with collection properties.

So you have to do the `Union` in memory:

```
var result = q1.AsEnumerable() // Continues the query in memory
               .Union(q2).ToList();
```

C# doesn't have any problem with equating anonymous types containing collections: it simply considers any collection member as unequal to another collections member. This does mean that the query can produce a collection containing non-unique results (same `Id`, same `Items`) which may not be expected when relying on `Union`'s implicit `Distinct`.

Comment: Hi Gert, can you explain to me why ienumerable iquerable works when the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb156049(v=vs.110).aspx) says it should be iquerable . ienumerable ?

Comment: `AsEnumerable()` forces the runtime to resolve to `Enumerable.Union` instead of `Queryable.Union`, so the two parts `q1` and `q2` must be evaluated as `IEnumerable` and can't be combined into one `IQueryable` expression tree any more.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, and the clarification for my answer !

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why, for some reason distinct is failing, maybe because it is anonymous type, and it is still IQuerable, I would suggest firing the query something like this

```
var q1 = ctx.Set<Type1>().Select(x => new { x.Id, x.Ref.Items }).ToList<object>();
var q2 = ctx.Set<Type2>().Select(x => new { x.Id, x.Ref.Items }).ToList<object>();
q1.Union(q2).ToList();
```

Note that in this case, Distinct will check for all properties equality, meaning if 2 objects have the same id but different items, both will be there.

if you don't care about distinct values, you can also use [concat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894(v=vs.110).aspx)

if you care about distinct and first option didn't work, you can use group by and implement your own distinct,
something like this

```
var q1 = ctx.Set<Type1>().Select(x => new { Id = x.Id, Items =x.Ref.Items });
var q2 = ctx.Set<Type2>().Select(x => new { Id = x.Id, Items = x.Ref.Items });
//this will group by id, and select the first object items
var qFinal = q1.concat(q2).GroupBy(e => e.id)
.select(e => new {e.key, e.First().Items})
 .ToList();
```

maybe you don't want `First()`, you can use whatever you want

Comment: `q1.Concat(q2)` will also throw an exception, see my answer. Also, `ToList<object>` isn't really elegant. `ToList()` will retain the anonymous types in the result. But using `AsEnumerable` once is enough.